# How can i get cilium to pass the failing connectivity test

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, eks, cilium

I am trying to deploy cilium to my **eks** cluster, for context, this cluster is a private cluster running behind a private subnet, and routed to the internet through a NAT gateway and then an internet gateway. I have been able to follow the cilium installation guid [here](https://docs.cilium.io/en/stable/installation/k8s-install-helm/). my nodes are tainted and i have patched the daemonset as the documentation asked.

When i run `cilium status`, i can see it is ok

```
    /¯¯\
 /¯¯\__/¯¯\    Cilium:             OK
 \__/¯¯\__/    Operator:           OK
 /¯¯\__/¯¯\    Envoy DaemonSet:    disabled (using embedded mode)
 \__/¯¯\__/    Hubble Relay:       disabled
    \__/       ClusterMesh:        disabled

Deployment        cilium-operator    Desired: 2, Ready: 2/2, Available: 2/2
DaemonSet         cilium             Desired: 3, Ready: 3/3, Available: 3/3
Containers:       cilium             Running: 3
                  cilium-operator    Running: 2
Cluster Pods:     2/2 managed by Cilium
Image versions    cilium             quay.io/cilium/cilium:v1.15.0@sha256:9cfd6a0a3a964780e73a11159f93cc363e616f7d9783608f62af6cfdf3759619: 3
                  cilium-operator    quay.io/cilium/operator-aws:v1.15.0@sha256:cf45167a8bb336c763046553c6a97c0d7f12f7e2a498dfb2340fa27832a81b3a: 2
```

However when i run `cilium connectivity test`, not all the test passes. the error is as shown below.

```
❌ 4/42 tests failed (30/321 actions), 13 tests skipped, 1 scenarios skipped:
Test [no-policies]:
  ❌ no-policies/pod-to-host/ping-ipv4-1: cilium-test/client-846d67868c-mpfrc (10.0.1.217) -> <NODE_IP> (<NODE_IP>:0)
  ❌ no-policies/pod-to-host/ping-ipv4-3: cilium-test/client-846d67868c-mpfrc (10.0.1.217) -> <NODE_IP> (<NODE_IP>:0)
  ❌ no-policies/pod-to-host/ping-ipv4-5: cilium-test/client-846d67868c-mpfrc (10.0.1.217) -> <NODE_IP> (<NODE_IP>:0)
  ❌ no-policies/pod-to-host/ping-ipv4-7: cilium-test/client2-865b7d7b6f-469vq (10.0.1.178) -> <NODE_IP> (<NODE_IP>:0)
  ❌ no-policies/pod-to-host/ping-ipv4-9: cilium-test/client2-865b7d7b6f-469vq (10.0.1.178) -> <NODE_IP> (<NODE_IP>:0)
  ❌ no-policies/pod-to-host/ping-ipv4-11: cilium-test/client2-865b7d7b6f-469vq (10.0.1.178) -> <NODE_IP> (<NODE_IP>:0)
Test [no-policies-extra]:
  ❌ no-policies-extra/pod-to-remote-nodeport/curl-0: cilium-test/client2-865b7d7b6f-469vq (10.0.1.178) -> cilium-test/echo-other-node (echo-other-node:8080)
  ❌ no-policies-extra/pod-to-remote-nodeport/curl-1: cilium-test/client2-865b7d7b6f-469vq (10.0.1.178) -> cilium-test/echo-other-node (echo-other-node:8080)
  ❌ no-policies-extra/pod-to-remote-nodeport/curl-2: cilium-test/client2-865b7d7b6f-469vq (10.0.1.178) -> cilium-test/echo-same-node (echo-same-node:8080)
  ❌ no-policies-extra/pod-to-remote-nodeport/curl-3: cilium-test/client2-865b7d7b6f-469vq (10.0.1.178) -> cilium-test/echo-same-node (echo-same-node:8080)
  ❌ no-policies-extra/pod-to-remote-nodeport/curl-4: cilium-test/client-846d67868c-mpfrc (10.0.1.217) -> cilium-test/echo-other-node (echo-other-node:8080)
  ❌ no-policies-extra/pod-to-remote-nodeport/curl-5: cilium-test/client-846d67868c-mpfrc (10.0.1.217) -> cilium-test/echo-other-node (echo-other-node:8080)
  ❌ no-policies-extra/pod-to-remote-nodeport/curl-6: cilium-test/client-846d67868c-mpfrc (10.0.1.217) -> cilium-test/echo-same-node (echo-same-node:8080)
  ❌ no-policies-extra/pod-to-remote-nodeport/curl-7: cilium-test/client-846d67868c-mpfrc (10.0.1.217) -> cilium-test/echo-same-node (echo-same-node:8080)
  ❌ no-policies-extra/pod-to-local-nodeport/curl-0: cilium-test/client2-865b7d7b6f-469vq (10.0.1.178) -> cilium-test/echo-other-node (echo-other-node:8080)
  ❌ no-policies-extra/pod-to-local-nodeport/curl-1: cilium-test/client2-865b7d7b6f-469vq (10.0.1.178) -> cilium-test/echo-same-node (echo-same-node:8080)
  ❌ no-policies-extra/pod-to-local-nodeport/curl-2: cilium-test/client-846d67868c-mpfrc (10.0.1.217) -> cilium-test/echo-other-node (echo-other-node:8080)
  ❌ no-policies-extra/pod-to-local-nodeport/curl-3: cilium-test/client-846d67868c-mpfrc (10.0.1.217) -> cilium-test/echo-same-node (echo-same-node:8080)
Test [allow-all-except-world]:
  ❌ allow-all-except-world/pod-to-host/ping-ipv4-1: cilium-test/client-846d67868c-mpfrc (10.0.1.217) -> 18.130.173.145 (<NODE_IP>:0)
  ❌ allow-all-except-world/pod-to-host/ping-ipv4-3: cilium-test/client-846d67868c-mpfrc (10.0.1.217) -> 18.171.241.88 (<NODE_IP>:0)
  ❌ allow-all-except-world/pod-to-host/ping-ipv4-5: cilium-test/client-846d67868c-mpfrc (10.0.1.217) -> 13.40.120.114 (<NODE_IP>:0)
  ❌ allow-all-except-world/pod-to-host/ping-ipv4-7: cilium-test/client2-865b7d7b6f-469vq (10.0.1.178) -> 18.130.173.145 (<NODE_IP>:0)
  ❌ allow-all-except-world/pod-to-host/ping-ipv4-9: cilium-test/client2-865b7d7b6f-469vq (10.0.1.178) -> 18.171.241.88 (<NODE_IP>:0)
  ❌ allow-all-except-world/pod-to-host/ping-ipv4-11: cilium-test/client2-865b7d7b6f-469vq (10.0.1.178) -> 13.40.120.114 (<NODE_IP>:0)
Test [host-entity]:
  ❌ host-entity/pod-to-host/ping-ipv4-1: cilium-test/client-846d67868c-mpfrc (10.0.1.217) -> <NODE_IP> (<NODE_IP>:0)
  ❌ host-entity/pod-to-host/ping-ipv4-3: cilium-test/client-846d67868c-mpfrc (10.0.1.217) -> <NODE_IP> (<NODE_IP>:0)
  ❌ host-entity/pod-to-host/ping-ipv4-5: cilium-test/client-846d67868c-mpfrc (10.0.1.217) -> <NODE_IP> (<NODE_IP>:0)
  ❌ host-entity/pod-to-host/ping-ipv4-7: cilium-test/client2-865b7d7b6f-469vq (10.0.1.178) -> <NODE_IP> (<NODE_IP>:0)
  ❌ host-entity/pod-to-host/ping-ipv4-9: cilium-test/client2-865b7d7b6f-469vq (10.0.1.178) -> <NODE_IP> (<NODE_IP>:0)
  ❌ host-entity/pod-to-host/ping-ipv4-11: cilium-test/client2-865b7d7b6f-469vq (10.0.1.178) -> <NODE_IP> (<NODE_IP>:0)
connectivity test failed: 4 tests failed
```

**Question**

How can i resolve this and get cilium running.

**PS**
I just swapped out the node ip addresses for the variable <NODE_IP> for the purpose of posting this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is disable assigning public IP addresses to EKS nodes.

You can configure that in the [Network Interfaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/create-launch-template.html#change-network-interface) in the [Launch Template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-launch-templates.html) that the EC2 instances are using. Set the "Auto-assign public IP" to Disable.